# Issues uninstalling an apparently Invisible file

Tags: windows-10, uninstall

I have a large [80gb] file I recently discovered on my PC. It's a game I used to play, but haven't for a long, long time. I tried to delete the file by going to the basic uninstall/change window however it apparently needs to be done through the client, which keeps throwing errors and can't even find the game in the first place.

The problem is, I can't either. I've looked for the pathname via the Uninstall/change tab and tried to actually find the games folder in programfilesx86 but it's plain not there. I tried checking the box for showing invisible folders, but no luck there either. I'm not really knowledgeable with computers so any help would be appreciated.

Below are screenshots of the Program and the space it takes up, and the folders starting with "W" in my program files x86.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the file actually exists? If you run something like `WinDirStat` on your `C:/` drive, does it pick up the file? Does `dir`?

Comment: dir doesn't. Idk what the first one is but I'll try it. If it doesn't then what do I do to rectify this error?

Comment: It seems as though [from pen and paper addition] the drive still counts the 80gb. My motivation for this is to free up the space so I can install something else :(

Comment: Find if there is any registry or folder_path of that app in `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` also in `WOW6432Node`.

Comment: Sorry could you explain it as if I was a dunce?

Comment: [WinDirStat](https://windirstat.net/) should show you exactly where the file is, as well as allow you to delete it right from the interface. Just make sure to run it as admin to make sure it's not a rights issue.

Comment: Ok, so WinDirStat allows me to account for folders that I couldn't see before, and it all adds up. I guess the rogue "80gb" number is just nonsense that's a minor inconvenience I'm gonna have to live with. Thanks. Also WinDirStat is quickly going to become one of my favourite programs

Comment: No problem, glad that you were able to get it worked out.